# "cordova already defined" in an Ionic application

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm getting a very strange error when I boot up my app:

> ⚡️  [error] - {"line":1,"column":789,"sourceURL":"capacitor://localhost/cordova.17fb1a7c009cbc8d5d42.js"}
> ⚡️  Error: cordova already defined
> ⚡️  URL: capacitor://localhost/cordova.17fb1a7c009cbc8d5d42.js
> ⚡️  cordova.17fb1a7c009cbc8d5d42.js:1:816

and it looks like this:

[image]

Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitor serves it’s own modified cordova.js for compatibility. It handles regular cordova.js file, but yours is called cordova.17fb1a7c009cbc8d5d42.js for some reason. Remove that file and it’s link as it’s causing problems with Capacitor’s cordova.js

Comment: thanks, it worked.  im not sure why that file appeared there in the first place, might have been because I originally created the ionic project using cordova..